# COUNT and DISTINCT without group by

Tags: mariadb

I've two tables. One with clients, other with products bought by clients.
When I want to get the list of all products and clients, I do:

```
    SELECT client_name, prod_id FROM TAB_CLIENT
    INNER JOIN TAB_PROD ON prod_client = client_name
```

So I get (eg)

- Henri - Potatoes
- Henri - Chocolate
- Tom - Beer

Nice. Now I want to know how many different clients I have.
So I tried to use COUNT and DISTINCT. Like this:

```
     SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT client_name) AS num_client, client_name, prod_id 
    FROM TAB_CLIENT
    INNER JOIN TAB_PROD ON prod_client = client_name
```

**I want to get:**

- 2 - Henri - Potatoes
- 2 - Henri - Chocolate
- 2 - Tom - Beer

So "2" in first colum as the whole number of different clients is 2 (Henri and Tom), name of the client at second colum and name of product as third colume.
But in fact if I add the count(distinct), I get only ONE result (seems like if there was a "group by" on num_client). And I don't want to GROUP BY on client_name as in this case I'll loose the product.

Is it possible to perform that in one query, or do I have to perform one select for counting and an other to get the result?

I notice all examples given in Stack are about Count/Distinct returning only number but not the number AND results.

Thanks

PS: I'm running MariaDB.

Comment: Why include TAB_PROD when asking "how many clients"?

Comment: Because I want the prod and the client in the result: Henri is a client, Potatoe is the product Henri bought. The problem came from the fact when you add count(distinct) you loose the results.

Comment: Your requirement "Now I want to know how many different clients I have" says nothing about products.  Please rephrase it.

Comment: Just read the post and see the query and the result: the query talk about client (TAB_CLIENT in the FROM part) AND of product (TAB_PROD in the INNER JOIN). If I DONT put the count(distinct) in the field list, I get the name of the client AND the product. If I add the count(distinct) in the field list, I loose the result. The question is to know if it's possible to get the number of client + the name of the clients + the product in one query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT
        ( SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT client_name) FROM TAB_CLIENT ) AS Number_of_clients,
        client_name,
        prod_id
    FROM TAB_CLIENT
    INNER JOIN TAB_PROD ON prod_client = client_name
```

Comment: OK I accept this answer, but this is what I was afraid of. So seems to be impossible without two select. Thanks.